# How to show that addition is primitive recursive?

Tags: recursion, primitive, automata

How do i show in an example with numbers that addition is primitve recursive.

I understand why it is primitive recursive through the proof but I just can't imagine how it works primitive recursively with numbers.

Answer (score 5):

To show that a function `φ` is primitive recursive, it suffices to provide a finite sequence of primitive recursive functions beginning with the constant, successor and projection functions and terminating with `φ` such that each function is constructed from prior functions by composition and primitive recursion. The primitive recursive addition function is defined

```
add(0,x)     = φ(x)
add(n + 1,x) = ψ(n,x,add(n,x))
  where φ = P[1/1]
        ψ = S ∘ P[3/3]
```

where `P[m/n]` is the `m`-ary projection function returning its `n`th argument for `n >= 1` and `n <= m`. To demonstrate that `add` is primitive recursive, we must construct `φ` and `ψ` from the basic functions:

```
1. P[1/1]                [Axiom]
2. P[3/3]                [Axiom]
3. S                     [Axiom]
4. S ∘ P[3/3]            [1,3 Composition]
6. PR(P[1/1],S ∘ P[3/3]) [1,4 Primitive Recursion]
```

The function `φ` is provided by the axioms of primitive recursive functions. The function `ψ` is constructed by composition from the primitive recursive functions `S` and `P[3/3]` in step (4). Finally, the function `add` is constructed from `φ` and `ψ` in step (6) by primitive recursion. To see how a value is computed by a primitive recursive function such as `add`, it suffices to systematically substitute the right-hand sides of function definitions where appropriate, then simplify. I've collapsed substitution and simplification of composition in the following example:

```
add(2,3) = S(P[3/3](1,3,add(1,3)))                 [Def. ψ]
         = S(P[3/3](1,3,S(P[3/3](0,3,add(0,3)))))  [Def. ψ]
         = S(P[3/3](1,3,S(P[3/3](0,3,P[1/1](3))))) [Def. φ]
         = S(P[3/3](1,3,S(P[3/3](0,3,3))))         [Def. P[1/1]]
         = S(P[3/3](1,3,S(3)))                     [Def. P[3/3]]
         = S(P[3/3](1,3,4))                        [Def. S]
         = S(4)                                    [Def. P[3/3]]
         = 5                                       [Def. S]
```

It's unclear precisely what you're asking, so I gave a general overview of the primitive recursive definition of addition, the proof that addition is primitive recursive, and provided an example computation. If you're still unclear, it might be helpful to perform computations on small values of primitive recursive functions.

Comment: What's the point of of phi having the first two arguments? Couldn't we just define it without them if phi only ever returns things based on the third argument?

Comment: It's been a while since I posted this response. I believe that φ is just a projection function. You might be confused by the use of φ as a variable in the first paragraph. Apologies for the confusion.